# Photoshop: What is the simplest and fastest way to draw geometrical shapes like a circle or square?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I wanted to draw a circle and I thought this could be accomplished by using a simple brush but there isn't a circle or square shape available.
Please note that by circle I mean a simple closed curve that divides the plane into two regions: an interior and an exterior. I don't mean a disk.

Comment: [Draw shapes with the shape tools in Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/drawing-shapes.html)

Comment: Thanks David, but this isn't a simple and fast way to do it. This would take at least 10 minutes to follow all the steps and draw a simple circle.. I do accept the fact that Photoshop isn't a program designed for drawing but this isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be the best answer:

1. Start a new project file. (I believe there is a size limit for this method - 600x600 px works fine.)
2. Using any method at all, draw the shape you want.
3. With the layer selected, hit Edit > Define brush preset
4. Now, you can open your working file, select the brush you just created in the brush menu, and click anywhere to instantly make that shape.

If you need multiple shapes, simply make multiple brushes, and you can even use hotkeys to switch between the brushes you've made.

There is of course more nuance if you're interested, simply searching "define brushes in photoshop" will lead you to lots more detailed information.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

After an hour I've finally found the brush set I need here: https://myphotoshopbrushes.com/brushes/id/3618/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.